# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'table_id' when attribute exists

Tags: python

Hi I'm having a hard time iteration over an array of dictionaries and can't figure it out what's failing

This is the data:

```
total = [{'table_id': 'IA_AUTO_2020-11-25', 'created': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 25, 5, 36, 1, 281000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)},
    {'table_id': 'IA_AUTO_2020-12-07', 'created': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 7, 5, 55, 4, 142000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)},
    {'table_id': 'IA_AUTO_2020-12-09', 'created': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 9, 5, 52, 55, 48000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}]
```

And this is the iteration code:

```
n=[]
d=[]
for t in total:
    n.append(t.table_id)
    d.append(t.created)
    total.append(t.table_id)
    total.append(t.created)
print(n)
```

But I get the error:

```
`        for t in total:
            print(t)
>           n.append(t.table_id)

   for t in total('trending_CL'):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`
```

**An important note: I can't change the loop structure, but rater modify the data structure to make it work**

I'm aware the issue must be rather simple, but really can't find it

Comment: Dictionaries use [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) to access their values - [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: `t.table_id` should be `t['table_id']`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. It is not clear what is `client.list_tables` here

Comment: @Tomerikoo I edited the question, since I was trying to mock the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the keys of a dictionary using `my_dict['my_key']`.

The following code should work:

```py
n=[]
d=[]
for t in client.list_tables('trending_CL'):
    n.append(t['table_id'])
    d.append(t['created'])
    total.append(t['table_id'])
    total.append(t['created'])
```

Comment: This throws an error : ´E    NameError: name 'table_id' is not defined´

Comment: @JuanPenaloza that's not possible from the above code...

Comment: Have you correctly transcripted the `'` before and after `table_id`? In your code you are looking for the variable called `table_id` and not for the string `'table_id'`

Comment: @Tomerikoo when I execute this potion of code in a new clean file, I got ```for t in total('trending_CL'):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable```  What do you mean with "not possible"?

Comment: @JuanPenaloza That's not the error you reported before. The one from before is not possible from the above code. The second error you mentioned is hard to say because we don't know what is `list_tables`. Post a [mre] in the question

Answer (score 2):

you are not calling a dict's attribute (for attributes it's correct to use `obj.attr`) but a dict's keys, in fact the items of a dict are NAMED BY KEY, so to access them you have to do `dict["key"]` and to modify them  `dict["key"] = "value"`

so your code should be:

```
n=[]
d=[]
for t in client.list_tables('trending_CL'):
    n.append(t['table_id'])
    d.append(t['created'])
    total.append(t['table_id'])
    total.append(t['created'])
```